# I have an excel doc with a list of a few thousand lines that needs to be

Tags: batch-file

I have an excel doc with a list of a few thousand lines that needs to be translated via "http://translation.babylon.com/english/to-dutch/" is there any way to create a .batch file to take one line at a time, translate it and paste the translation into a file (all of the lines need to be in the same file)
thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: Off topic, but I'm not too sure if I would trust a company which has "How it works?" as one of their headers.

Comment: You're better off using VBA for any batch-processing of excel data.

Comment: You could convert the file to csv, iterate it and have curl query Babylon and then parse the result. But this is crap, so either use a "real" scripting language or do it from inside excel

Comment: I would suspect that that web service would not welcome a few thousand requests to its server from a single IP address...

Comment: thank you "something dark"!!